# Void symbols after enabling native compilation

Tags: native-comp

I updated my Emacs from 25 to 28.1 version (as part of OS update), and now on startup there is an error

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: kill-region
```

as well as a lot of `comp` warnings. On similar machine same `.emacs.d` works perfectly, but native compilation is disabled there.

After `init.el` fails to load, I **can** call `kill-region` in scratch and it works.

I found where this error comes from (`.emacs.d/core/prelude-editor.el`), but if I comment out offending line (`(crux-with-region-or-line kill-region)`), other errors comes up. So I believe there is some problem with native compilation. I planning to try compile Emacs from sources without native compilation to test that theory.

UPD. Error happening only on second start of Emacs (or rather when there is no compiled .elc files).

Comment: This is a guess, but I suspect that library fails to require all of its dependencies, and the native-compilation process has surfaced the issue by virtue of compiling things in a more isolated fashion.

Comment: You mean that it lack some `require` calls? I have zero idea how `kill-region` could not be imported, it is like built-in function.

Comment: Indeed it is.  It is not a variable, OTOH (refer back to your error).  I strongly suspect a necessary macro definition has not been loaded at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As expected (see earlier comments), it's a missing macro on account of a missing `require`.

```
commit 36b3950d7d315736374b1bcb77b3583c9a895fc0
Date:   Mon Apr 11 02:10:23 2022 -0400

    Fix "Symbol's value as variable is void: kill-region" errors in Emacs 29.0.50 (#1356)
```

```
diff --git a/core/prelude-editor.el b/core/prelude-editor.el
index 2151048..2a342e8 100644
--- a/core/prelude-editor.el
+++ b/core/prelude-editor.el
@@ -166,6 +166,7 @@
 ;; note - this should be after volatile-highlights is required
 ;; add the ability to cut the current line, without marking it
 (require 'rect)
+(require 'crux)
 (crux-with-region-or-line kill-region)
 
 ;; tramp, for sudo access
```

https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/commit/36b3950d7d315736374b1bcb77b3583c9a895fc0

I suggest that you use whichever process is recommended in order to update your `prelude` installation to the latest code, as I expect other incompatibilities will exist in your current version, given the very large version jump you're making (from Emacs 25 to 28).

Comment: Hmmmm, I'm sure I updated it quite recently. However I ran prelude-update again and it worked. Thanks!